# Proof of the Structure theorem of finitely generated graded modules over graded PID's

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, graded-modules

I am looking for a proof of the structure theorem of finitely generated graded modules over graded PID's:

Let $R$ be a graded PID and $M$ be a finitely generated graded module over $R$. Then $M$ decomposes uniquely as $$M \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \Sigma^{\alpha_i} R\  \oplus\  \bigoplus_{j=1}^m \Sigma^{\gamma_i} R/d_j R$$ where $d_j \in R$ are homogeneous elements so that $d_j \mid d_{j+1}$ , $\alpha_i, \gamma_j \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\Sigma^\alpha$ denotes an $\alpha$-shift upwards in grading.

But i can't find anything. Does anybody know where i could find a proof of this theorem? I know how to proof the usual structure theorem of finitely generated modules, is there an easy way to translate this result to the graded case ? I would guess that one obtains $M \cong R^n\ \oplus\ \bigoplus_{j=1}^m R/d_j R$ by the usal structure theorem , but the isomorphism is just a usal isomorphism of modules. To get a graded isomorphism one has to eventually shift the terms on the right side in grading.

Comment: Yes every algebra text covers the standard case, but my question was about a proof of the graded case or how to get from the standard case to the graded case.

Comment: my bad. i don't know how dis/similar the proofs are, but retracting close vote

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the decomposition of graded $k[x]$-modules is important in the study of persistent homology; papers on the subject are the only place in the literature where I could find a treatment of graded PIDs.

An algorithm to find the graded Smith normal form of a matrix is discussed in Section 3.1.3 of the paper

Primoz Skraba and Mikael Vejdemo-Johansson, *Persistence modules: Algebra and algorithms*, [arXiv:1302.2015](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.2015v2).

Although the algorithm is stated only for graded $k[x]$-modules, the authors mention that it works over any graded PID.  Once one has a graded Smith normal form, the structure theorem for finitely generated graded modules can be easily proved.

Comment: Thank you i will take a look at it, i also came across graded modules by the persistence literature. The theorem is stated in the paper "computig persistent  homology" by Carlsson. But i cant imagine this theorem wasnt proved before persistence came up.

Comment: @Hyperion It does seem unlikely that no textbook should contain the graded version of this fundamental result.

Comment: i read the paper but i still struggle do understand how i get the theorem im looking for from there, could i ask you do explain it to me ? I understand that that they compute the usal smith-normal form without permuting the rows and colums in a way to maintain homogeneous bases but i struggle to choose this homogeneous to get what i want.